# Issue disabling hyperlink in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link that needs to be disabled once I click on it until the page reloads again. The main purpose is to limit the user from clicking on the link multiple times.

Below is my link:

```
<a href="/User/faces/profile.xhtml?id=20521&amp;itemNo=-1" onclick="this.disabled=true;document.body.style.cursor='wait';" style="padding: 10px 5px;">Profile</a>
```

This works fine on ie11, but not on chrome or iPad.

Is there anything that I am missing? Any help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: How do you know it is not disabled if it redirects you to other page

Comment: The JSF pre-render methods in the new page are getting executed multiple times based on the number of clicks until the page reloads.

Comment: try checking console. is it clear?

Comment: You'll have to `preventDefault()` and, modify the element, and then redirect to the profile.xhml page programmatically.

Comment: Yes, it is clear. I don't see any errors on chrome console.

Comment: check out my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **disabled** *property* of an element //- they are now calling *attribute* - in other plain browsers related to Netscape Navigator doesn't have support the property *disabled* on other than a narrow group of page **controls** they also mistake for *elements*...

The most recent table of support are the following tags:

`<button>
<fieldset>
<input>
<optgroup>
<option>
<select>
<textarea>`

Meaning :  There is no support for Link \ Anchor elements, except in versions of IE 1997 and up.

For a wider support I suggest you try using a *button* tag for your code.

Comment: Added a hidden button that is clicked onClick of the link. Once the button is clicked I am disabling it from further clicks. It solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can't disable an anchor element by using `disabled`. There are some ways to achieve it of course. One of them  would be to set `pointer-events: none` per css (but you would lose the `wait`-cursor style with it). There are others like removing the `href` attribute or changing it, but this could have sideeffects depending on your environment as well.

My suggestion would be to just keep a boolean state and prevent execution if the link was already clicked:

```js
const link = document.querySelector('#myLink');
let redirected = false;
link.addEventListener('click', ev => {
    if (redirected) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    } else {
        console.log('click');
        redirected = true;
        link.style.cursor = 'wait';
    }
});
```

```html
<a href="http://www.google.de" target="_blank" id="myLink">My Link</a>
```

Comment: It worked on my local server, but had problems when deployed on Solaris. It was getting submitted multiple times. So, eventually I added a hidden button and click it using JavaScript onClick event. Now, disable the hidden button onClick of it. Not an elegant solution, but it resolved the issue.